# .Automation Error. Unable to copy array of data into powerpoint slides from excel worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

```
Dim myPresentation, mySlide, PowerPointApp, shp As Object
Dim MySlideArray, MyRangeArray As Variant
Dim x As Long

Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation

  MySlideArray = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

  MyRangeArray = Array(Worksheets("Name File").Range("A1:C10"), _
                       Worksheets("Age File").Range("A1:C10"), _
                       Worksheets("Location File").Range("A1:C10"), _
                       Worksheets("DOB File").Range("A1:C10"))

  For x = LBound(MySlideArray) To UBound(MySlideArray)
        MyRangeArray(x).Copy
        Set shp = PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
  Next x

  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  ThisWorkbook.Activate
```

On debugging, sometimes the code runs all the way but only the first range gets copied to powerpoint, while rest are not. Othertimes, i get a run-time error while using ShapeRange (pasting). Where did i do wrong? Please help. Learning VBA since 1 week.
[Error looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8y6R.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to copy each range referenced in `MyRangeArray` and past them into their respective slide referenced in `MySlideArray`.

The following line of code will paste each range into their respective slide, and returns a `ShapeRange`.

```
Set shp = myPresentation.slides(MySlideArray(x)).Shapes.Paste
```

To return a `Shape` object instead, try the following...

```
Set shp = myPresentation.slides(MySlideArray(x)).Shape`s.Paste(1)
```

By the way, `myPresentation`, `mySlide`, and `PowerPointApp` are declared as `Variant`, since you haven't specified a type.  To declare them as `Object`, you'll need to specify the type as follows...

```
Dim myPresentation as Object, mySlide as Object, PowerPointApp as Object, shp As Object
```

And, the same thing applies to your next declaration line.